# Mips : Count Number of lowercase letters using nested functions

Tags: assembly, mips

Simply , the user enter a string ... and I have to count number of lowercase letters using two functions(procedures) :

**countSmallLetters** function that loop on string and each time call function **isSmall** to check whether this character is small or not , if yes increase counter (number of lowercase letters) by 1

I have trase my code more than once -even on a paper - it seem that the logic is right but it print the counter(number of lowercase letters) with 0 value ?!

Any help ? thanks in advance ...

```
.data
str: .asciiz""

.text
main:

la $a0,str   #Enter Stirng
li $v0,8
syscall

jal countSmallLetters

move $a0,$v0    #Print Result (number of lowercase letters)
li $v0,1
syscall

#end
li $v0,10
syscall

countSmallLetters:
    subu $sp,$sp,4 
    sw $ra,0($sp)       #use stack to save tha main address(the link)

    add $v0,$zero,0 #counter (return)

    add $t2,$zero,1     #char is small
    add $t3,$zero,0     #char is capital

    loop:
    lb $a1,0($a0)
    beq $a1,$zero,backToMain    #terminator
    jal isSmall               #check if small or not
    add $a0,$a0,1
    beq $v1,$t2,increase
    j loop
    increase:
    add $v0,$v0,1
    j loop

    backToMain:
    lw $ra,0($sp)
    addu $sp,$sp,4
    jr $ra


isSmall:
    add $t0,$zero,97
    add $t1,$zero,122

    bge $a1,$t0,first   #a1>=97
    j out
    first:  
    ble $a1,$t1,second  #a1<=122
    j out
    second:
    add $v1,$zero,1         #char is small
    out:
    add $v1,$zero,0         #char is capital
    jr $ra
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `$v1` to `1` but you overwrite it immediately with a `0`. You could add a `jr $ra` immediately before the `out:` label, or zero `$v1` initially, such as:

```
second:
    add $v1,$zero,1         #char is small
    jr $ra
out:
    add $v1,$zero,0         #char is capital
    jr $ra
```